# memory crash when storing NSOperationQueues in a NSCache

Tags: ios, iphone, cocoa-touch

I have a `UITableView` that loads thumbnails into cells aynchronously as follows:

```
NSBlockOperation *operation = [NSBlockOperation blockOperationWithBlock:
^{
    ThumbnailButtonView *thumbnailButtonView = [tableViewCell.contentView.subviews objectAtIndex:i];
    UIImage *image = [self imageAtIndex:startingThumbnailIndex + i];
    [self.thumbnailsCache setObject: image forKey:[NSNumber numberWithInt:startingThumbnailIndex + i]];

    [[NSOperationQueue mainQueue] addOperationWithBlock:
    ^{
        UITableViewCell *tableViewCell = [self cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
        if (tableViewCell)
        {
            [activityIndicatorView stopAnimating];
            [self setThumbnailButtonView:thumbnailButtonView withImage:image];
        }

    }];
}];

[self.operationQueue addOperation:operation];
[self.operationQueues setObject:operation forKey:[NSNumber numberWithInt:startingThumbnailIndex + i]];
```

As per a technique I learned in a WWDC presentation, I store all of my operation queues in a `NSCache` called `operationQueues` so that later on I can cancel them if the cell scrolls off the screen (there are 3 thumbnails in a cell):

```
- (void) tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didEndDisplayingCell:(UITableViewCell *)cell forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    NSInteger startingThumbnailIndex = [indexPath row] * self.thumbnailsPerCell;

    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
    {
        NSNumber *key = [[NSNumber alloc] initWithInt:i + startingThumbnailIndex];
        NSOperation *operation = [self.operationQueues objectForKey:key];

        if (operation)
        {
            [operation cancel];
            [self.operationQueues removeObjectForKey:key];
        }
    }

}
```

However, I notice if I repeatedly launch, load, then close my `UITableView`, I start recieving memory warnings, and then eventually the app crashes. When I remove this line:

```
[self.operationQueues setObject:operation forKey:[NSNumber numberWithInt:startingThumbnailIndex + i]];
```

The memory issues go away. Does anyone have any clue on why storing the operation queues in a cache or an array causes the app to crash?

Answer (score 0):

**Note: I learnt about `NSCache` and `NSOperationQueue` a couple of days ago so I might be wrong.**

I don't think that this is a problem with `NSOperationQueue`, you are adding images to your `thumbnailsCache` but when the view scrolls off-screen they are still in memory. I am guessing that when the cells scroll back in, you re-create your images. This is probably clogs your memory.

Also, shouldn't you be caching your images instead of your operations?

**EDIT**

I did some detailed testing with `NSCache` by adding images and strings until my app crashed. It doesn't seem to be evicting any items so I wrote my custom cache, which seems to work:

```
@implementation MemoryManagedCache : NSCache

- (id)init
{
    self = [super init];

    if (self) {
        [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(reduceMemoryFootprint) name:UIApplicationDidReceiveMemoryWarningNotification object:nil];
    }

    return self;
}

- (void)reduceMemoryFootprint
{
    [self setCountLimit:self.countLimit/2];
}

@end
```

Comment: I am caching the images in the thumbnails cache. I don't think it's the recreating the images that's clogging memory because if I remove the line I mentioned above it works fine. It has to do with storing the NSOperationQueues in the data structure for whatever reason. Thanks for the response - it's a weird problem, might be an apple bug.

Comment: You are probably right. [Other people](http://www.photosmithapp.com/index.php/2013/10/photosmith-3-0-2-photo-caching-and-ios-7/) are also having problems with `NSCache`.

Comment: I'm not even so sure it's NSCache because I've also tried using a NSMutableArray and gotten the same result. I think it's just some issue with hanging onto the pointers of the NSOperationQueues.